# 960 Grid system Design Help

Tags: css, grid, system, stylesheet

I started to design website using the 960 grid system everything works amazingly apart from the following

```
 <div class="grid_1 pagelink prefix_12"><p><a href="">1</a></p></div>
  <div class="grid_1 pagelink"><p><a href="">2</a></p></div>
  <div class="grid_1  page"><p><a href="">3</a></p></div>
  <div class="grid_1 pagelink"><p><a href="">4</a></p></div>
```

I need the above 4 links to be in a container, so that i can have a white background across all for boxes, so I am doing this:

```
<div id="somecontainer">
    ... the code above
</div>
```

I also tried

```
<div class="grid_4">
    ... the code above
</div>
```

But this does not work. If the above had worked I wanted to add this style:

```
#somecontainer{
   background:white;
   overflow:auto; /*  I added this but not difference  */
 }
```

I hope you can help me fix this problem

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
#somecontainer{
   width:960px; /* or 100% */
   background:white;
   overflow:hidden; /*  I added this but not difference  */
 }
```

Comment: thanks, if it is possible for you to explain the difference (or the importance) of "overflow:hidden" vs overflow: auto; that be great - just so I can get my head around it.  But thanks again

Comment: overflow:hidden hides any content that flows out of the element - overflow:auto doesn't hide the content that flows out of the element but instead it creates a scrollbar so your able to see the overflowed content if you are interested in learning more about this I'd recommend you visit these sites for a better reference. http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp | http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/